# Rails include a conditional polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, left-join, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association:
Following the rails association model picture from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and  Supposing employees is my Content and pictures is my translations i need perform an filtered association.

[image]

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :translations,:as => :transl
end

class Translation < ApplicationRecord
   enum idiom: [ :EN, :NO]
   belongs_to :transl, :polymorphic => true
end
```

As a result I would like to have a json with my content but only with specific idiom for that i have something like this:

```
 Content.all.to_json(:include => {:translations => {:only => [:text, :idiom],:where =>{idiom: "EN"}}})
```

I tried to create a method to be included on to_json, but methods inside it is meant to be only getters.

i tried also left outer join but it don't work as well:

```
SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "translations" ON "translations"."transl_id" = "contents"."id"  WHERE (translations.idiom=0)
```

To work i must to perform a raw query enforcing to get some results from the left side **i assume that could have some contents without translation** such as:

```
SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "translations" ON  "contents"."id"  = "translations"."transl_id" **OR "contents"."id" >0**  WHERE (translations.idiom="EN")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

*SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "translations" ON  "contents"."id"  = "translations"."transl_id" **OR "contents"."id" >0**  WHERE (translations.idiom="EN")*

can be ===>

```
@lang="EN"
Content.where(:id > 0).includes(:translations).where({:translations =>{:idiom=>@lang}})
```

Comment: comparison error : `comparison of Symbol with 0 failed from (irb):2:in '>' `. After correcting error by `.where("contents.id > 0")` this will add another AND operator after Left outer join: `SELECT * FROM "contents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "translations" ON "translations"."transl_id" = "contents"."id" AND "translations"."transl_type" = ? WHERE (contents.id > 0) AND "translations"."idiom" = ?  `